# Deselect checkbox if confirm is false

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have a series of checkboxes that uses can click on which will cause a form to submit. Before I submit the form I wasn't them to confirm that's what they want to do.
I can't seem to uncheck the box if they choose cancel and I'm not sure what is wrong with the code I'm using. Can anyone help?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="box_1" id="box_1" value="1" onclick="javascript:if (confirm('Are you sure?')){this.form.submit();}else{document.getElementById('box_1').checked = 'false';};" />
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Maybe `false` is not a string? Try removing `'`'s. Just `smth=false`

Answer (score 2):

typo mistake `'false'` is a string, which instead should have been simply `false`

```
document.getElementById('box_1').checked = false;
```

Comment: I tried it without the quote first and added them when it didn't work without. I'll try again though.